# Processing JavaDStream at fixed intervals

Tags: java, machine-learning, apache-spark

I am building a Stream Learning application using Apache Spark. My application needs to process the streamed data at regular intervals but before or after these intervals, it can let it pass without any processing. So, I am not interested in all the stream items but some of them that show up at some specific intervals (at least for training part) I could not figure out how to process only some windows in the stream while ignoring the others.

Comment: Are your events timestamped or do you rely on the streaming interval?

Comment: they are timestamped

Comment: I see what you are suggesting I can simply filter the stream depending on the timestamp. Thank you.

Comment: That's where I was going indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the messages contain a timestamp, a way to approach this is to filter the 'interesting' messages matching the intended interval and pass those to processing by Spark.

```
val dstream = ???
val targetStream = dstream.filter(msg => withinInterval(timestamp(msg))}
targetStream.forEachRDD(rdd => // do something with the filtered elements)
```